# JFrame Trigger Events on Close

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I know the title isn't very explanatory, I was unsure of how to phrase the question. What I have is a GUI that I want to trigger an event when the window in closed (including when you force quit the window/application). Thank you in advance for any help!!! Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
public class NotAVirus extends JFrame {
private JTextField statusField = new JTextField(20);
private JButton yesButton = new JButton("Open");
private JButton noButton = new JButton("Close");
private static NotAVirus app = new ImLost();

public static void main() {
    app.setVisible(true);
    app.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}    

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
public ImLost() {
    super("ImLost");
    statusField.setText("There's No Escape");
    statusField.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    statusField.setEditable(false);
    add(statusField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    p.add(yesButton);
    p.add(noButton);
    add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    yesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                app.setVisible(false);
                for(int i = 0; i <= 10000; i ++)
                {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ImLost");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                    JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
                    emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 1));
                    frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                    //Display the window.
                    frame.setLocation((int)(Math.random() * ((1280) + 1)),(int)(Math.random() * ((800) + 1)));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
    noButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                app.setVisible(false);
                for(int i = 0; i <= 10000; i ++)
                {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ImLost");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                    JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
                    emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 1));
                    frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                    //Display the window.
                    frame.setLocation((int)(Math.random() * ((1280) + 1)),(int)(Math.random() * ((800) + 1)));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
    p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 35));
    pack();
}
```

Comment: _including when you force quit the window/application_ If you mean "when someone kills the process" i think it wouldn't be possible, as the process gets _killed_. If you mean "when the application freezes and the user forces it to close" I think it wouldn't be possible too, as the application is _frozen_ and it's _not responding_

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `WindowListener` to the `JFrame`:

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        //window is being closed
    }
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        //window is closed
    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }

});
```

> I want to trigger an event when the window in closed (including when you force quit the window/application)

If you mean "when someone kills the process" i think it wouldn't be possible, as the process ***gets killed*** and so stops its execution *immediately*. If you mean "when the application freezes and the user forces it to close" I think it wouldn't be possible too, usually if you force the quit of an application, it means that it's *frozen* and it's *not responding anymore*, so executing other code of it wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("window closed");
            }
        });
```

You dont need to override all methods.